# Leaked memory,segmentation fault,C

Tags: c, linux

gcc shows 0 errors, but valgrind shows that memory leaks and I cant execute my program because segmentation fault (core dumped) any  suggestions?
I checked allocation alone and its fine valgrind shows 0 memory leaked.There is a problem somewhere in file operations but I cant find it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* arrsize(FILE *plik)
{
if (plik == NULL) {
    printf("Error: file pointer is null.");
    return 0;
}
int* size;
fscanf(plik, "%d", &size);
return size;
}


int main()
{
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, a = 0;

FILE *fp;
if ((fp = fopen("matrix.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: file pointer is null.\n");
    return 1;
}
int size = arrsize(fp);

printf("Array size is %d x %d   ", size, size);



double **arr = (double **)malloc(size * sizeof(double *));
for (i; i < size; i++)
    arr[i] = (double *)malloc(size * sizeof(double));


for (j; j < size; j++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[i][j]);
}



for (i; i < size; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {

        printf("%lf\n", &arr[i][j]);
    }
}

for (k; k < size; k++) {
    free(arr[k]);
}
free(arr);

fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Or produce a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue. At the very least, explain what your program is *supposed* to be doing.

Comment: And if valgrind is reporting leaks, then present the relevant part of its report.

Comment: At very first glance, however, why is your `arrsize()` function reading a pointer value via the `scanf` directive for a signed decimal integer?  Are you sure you don't mean for it to read and return an `int`, instead?

Comment: Yes and no, @usr.  It is not initialized, but a pointer to it is passed to `scanf`.  Presumably, this is intended to set a value for it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger he could only do that if `size` points to a valid address and in this case no!. And even if it is a valid address you don't have to pass the address, just pass the pointer `fscanf(plik, "%d", size);`

Comment: Is your compiler not complaining at this `int size = arrsize(fp);`

Comment: @SeekAddo, you are missing the point.  He is passing the *address* of `size` not `size` itself.  That would be perfectly fine if the corresponding `scanf` directive were `%p` instead of `%d`.  But, nevertheless, probably not what he actually wants to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yea i got what you mean, this case here is not doing the %p

Answer (score 3):

Change arrsize to actually return an `int`, not an `int*`:

```
int arrsize(FILE *plik)
{
    if (plik == NULL) {
        printf("Error: file pointer is null.");
        return 0;
    }
    int size;
    fscanf(plik, "%d", &size);
    return size;
}
```